# Typescript: Can't use import state outside a module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using typescript and node express. After I found a post like this title, I tried everything that said in it. No working.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mm-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^20.10.0"
  },
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "build": "rm -f -r dist && tsc && tsc-alias",
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -d ./src/entities/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.9",
    "@types/node": "^18.6.4",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.8",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "paths": {
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "@config": ["src/config"],

      "@controllers/*": ["src/controllers/*"],
      "@controllers": ["src/controllers"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src/"],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules"]
}
```

nodemon.json

```
{
  "ignore": ["node_modules"],
  "watch": ["./src/**/*", ".env"],
  "exec": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts",
  "ext": ".ts, .js"
}
```

i am able to run `npm run dev` for development local. now, i am trying to build and run builded version. `npm run build` builds dist folder , but when i run `npm start`, error is

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your package.json:

```
"type": "module"
```

Comment: /dist/index.js:5
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/path/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

Comment: It seems like you are using both module syntax - like import, and commonjs syntax - like module.exports

"type": "module" makes the code use the module syntax by default. If there is a specific file you still want to use the commonjs syntax - rename it from file.js to file.cjs (or do the reverse - remove the "type": "module" to make all files be commonjs by default, and the module files rename from file.js to file.mjs)

Answer (score 0):

**In tsconfig.json file change:**

"module": "commonjs" => "module": "esnext" (or "module": "es6")

For more details see this https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module